# W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Error while running "sudo apt-get update"

```
 xyz@xyz:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                           
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                 
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-fonville/android-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/lives/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Fetched 214 kB in 6s (37.1 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
```

Answer (score 4):

This isn’t an error, it’s a warning, and it’s only telling you that you have the same repository listed twice in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. You can remove the second definition by deleting line 7 of that file.